# NSMutableArray addObject: -[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I have tried to initialize my NSMutableArray 100 ways from Sunday, and NOTHING is working for me. I tried setting it equal to a newly allocated and initialized NSMutableArray, just allocating, initializing the variable by itself, every combination I could think of and always the same result.

Here's the code:

Object.h

```
NSMutableArray *array;

@property (copy) NSMutableArray *array;
```

Object.m

```
@synthesize array;

if ( self.array ) {
    [self.array addObject:anObject];
}
else {
    self.array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:anObject, nil];
}
```

NOTE: In debug "anObject" is NOT nil at time of execution...

I have tested anObject and it isThe initialization works just fine, but I keep getting the error below when I try to addObject: to self.array.

> 2010-07-10 11:52:55.499 MyApp[4347:1807] -[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x184480
>
> 2010-07-10 11:52:55.508 MyApp[4347:1807] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x184480'

Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would like to tip my hat to Georg Fritzsche. I did end up needing to use (copy) instead of (retain), and I would not have known what to do without his input.

```
//@property (copy) NSMutableArray *array;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *array; //overridden method is non-atomic as it is coded and should be reflected here.
```

If you wish to use (copy) on a mutable object you must override the "setter" method as follows...

```
- (void)setArray:(NSArray *)newArray {

    if ( array != newArray ) { 
        [array release];
        array = [newArray mutableCopy];
//      [array retain]; // unnecessary as noted by Georg Fritzsche
    }

    return;
}
```

NOTE: You will get a compiler warning: Incompatible Objective-C types initializing 'struct NSArray *', expected 'struct NSMutableArray *' I chose to declare the newArray parameter as an (NSArray *), because you are given the flexibility to have any array passed and correctly copied to your (NSMutableArray *) variable. If you wish to declare the newArray parameter as an (NSMutableArray *) you will still need to leave the mutableCopy method in place to get your desired results.

Cheers to Georg!
Z@K!

Comment: Note that your property declaration doesn't have to match the ivar type, so you should use `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *array;` in your case. Also note that your property is implicitly atomic, but the implementation of your setter is not - see [Atomicity](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW28).

Comment: Finally, `-mutableCopy` already returns a retained instance, thus there is no need for `[array retain]` - see [Object Ownership Policy](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW1).

Comment: Thank you again, Mr. Fritzsche. I was curious about that extra retain, but it seemed to work in my program. Apparently I have a bug elsewhere. :-/ You are the man, thank you for contributing on this post and, inadvertently, my program; I appreciate your time!

Sincerely,
Z@K!

Comment: While your @property declaration doesn't have to match, switching the property to NSArray instead of NSMutableArray has raised several compiler warnings everywhere I use a NSMutableArray method on self.array, saying, "'NSArray' may not respond to '-addObject:'". So I have opted to leave the NSMutableArray in place in the @property declaration and deal with the one compiler warning described in NOTE:.

Comment: My additional retain comes from this... `@property (copy) NSArray *anotherArray; @property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray array;` when I set anotherArray equal to array `anotherArray = array; array = nil;` It was releasing all the objects inside of anotherArray, even though it has (copy) on the @property. This was blowing my mind. The additional retain I was putting in the setter was offsetting the release. I was able to fix it all by changing my code to... `anotherArray = [array copy];` Simple enough.

Comment: I ended up selecting my own answer, because it would give the best detail to someone else looking for this information, but I would like to give all credit to Georg Fritzsche; this is really his answer reformatted...

Comment: If you implement you own setter as per above. Do you then remove the @synthesize statement?

Comment: You need to use the @synthesize statement, so it will implement the "getter" method for you. Then you will override the "setter" method it creates as you build your own like the above example.

Answer (score 86):

The synthesized setter for `@property (copy)` sends a `copy` message to the array, which results in an immutable copy.

You have no choice but the implement the setter yourself here, as [detailed](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW32) in the Objective-C guide.

Comment: ABSOLUTELY CORRECT! I realized it as I was writing my post, and I posted my resolution below. I didn't really consider overriding the setter, but in my case I don't really need a copy so my solution worked out for me. Thanks for the quick reply! - Z@K!

Comment: The link to the Objective-C guide is broken.

Answer (score 76):

As I was proof reading my post, a thought occurred to me and I answered my own question. This resolution was obscure enough that I decided to go ahead, create the post and answer it myself (so any other newbies, like myself, won't get hung up).

My mistake was in...

```
@property (copy) NSMutableArray *array;
```

it should have been...

```
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *array;
```

The error was not happening in the way I was executing my code, but rather in the way the anObject was attempting to "copy" the NSMutableArray array.

As we all know...

```
mutableArray = [mutableArray copy];
```

is not always (or ever, in my experience) equal to...

```
mutableArray = [mutableArray mutableCopy];
```

And this was the source of my problem. By simply switching the @property from (copy) to (retain) I solved my problem.

Comment: i was having the same problem,i solved my changing property from copy to retain... @Zak +1 for your answer.

Comment: `mutableCopy` just saved my live

Answer (score 4):

Have some indexes (into a data array elsewhere) and wanted to have them in numerical order (for a good reason). Crashing until added mutableCopy at the end. Totally puzzled, until I recalled that using **Objective-C literal @[] returns a non-mutable array**.

```
NSMutableArray *a = [@[@(self.indexA), @(self.indexB)] mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"%@", a);
[indexArray sortUsingComparator: ^(NSNumber *obj1, NSNumber *obj2) {
    return [obj1 compare:obj2];
}];
NSLog(@"%@", a);
```

Thanx, Zak!

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error, even though my properties were strong (using ARC) and I allocated the array with NSMutableArray.

What was happening was that I was archiving the mutable array (as it contains custom objects) for future use and when decoding it, it returns an immutable copy.

Hope it helps anyone out there.

Answer (score 1):

The error came about as a result of attempting to add an object to an NSMutableArray type that was actually pointing to an NSArray object. This type of scenario is shown in some demo code below:

```
NSString *test = @"test";
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[mutableArray addObject:test];
NSArray *immutableArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
mutableArray = immutableArray;
[mutableArray addObject:test]; // Exception: unrecognized selector
```

From the above code, it is easy to see that a subclass type is being assigned to a superclass type. In Java, for instance, this would immediately have been flagged as an error (conversion error between types), and the problem resolved fairly quickly. To be fair to Objective-C, a warning is given when attempting to perform an incompatible assignment, however, this simply just does not seem to be enough sometimes and the result can be a real pain for developers. Fortunately, this time around, it was not myself who bore most of this pain :P

Answer (score 0):

I got bitten by this exception for a typo I've made, maybe it'll save someone 5 min. of their time:

I wrote:

```
NSMutableArray *names = [NSArray array];
```

instead of:

```
NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray array];
```

The compiler has no problem with that because NSMutableArray is also an NSArray, but it crashes when trying to add an object.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error saying : unrecognized selector sent to instance for NSMutable array.. After going through a lot of things, I figured out that I was using my mutable array as a property as

`@property (assign, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;`

while copy pasting and not paying attention and it was causing the problem.

The solution us that I changed it to strong type(you can change it to any other type like strong/weak,etc.. depending your requirement). So solution in my case was :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;
```

So, be careful while copy pasting! Do check once.

Answer (score -3):

This exception can happen if one of the objects in the array is null.

Comment: Not this particular error, no.  You get a different exception if trying to insert a nil object.

Comment: Beyond that, arrays can contain NSNull just fine.