# NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex: throws invalid argument exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm writing an application to show some news from a portal. The news are fetched using a JSON file from the Internet and then stored into a NSMutableArray using the CoreData Model. Obviously a user can't delete the news from the JSON file on the Internet, but he can hide them locally. The problems come out here, where I have the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    if( !moc ){
        moc = [[NewsFetcher sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];
    }
    [[dataSet objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setEliminata:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    NSError *error;
    if( ![moc save:&error] ){
        NSLog( @"C'è stato un errore!" );
    }
    [dataSet removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
}
```

The line:

> [dataSet
>   removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cause my apps to crash with the following error:

> 2010-07-12 19:08:16.021
>   ProvaVideo[284:207] *** -[_PFArray
>   removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x451c820
>   2010-07-12 19:08:16.022
>   ProvaVideo[284:207] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '*** -[_PFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x451c820'

I'm trying to understand why it doesn't work but I can't. 
If I re-launch the app, the new is correctly logically cancelled.
Any suggestions?? Thanks in advance.

---

Interface:

```
@interface ListOfVideo : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> { 
    NSMutableArray *dataSet;
} 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *dataSet;

// In the .m file:
@synthesize dataSet;
```

Initialization in `viewDidLoad`:

```
dataSet = (NSMutableArray *) [[NewsFetcher sharedInstance] 
                                fetchManagedObjectsForEntity:@"News" 
                                withPredicate:predicate
                                withDescriptor:@"Titolo"]; 
[dataSet retain];
```

`updateDatabase` ... this is when checking for new news from the net, I add them in the MutableArray:

```
[dataSet addObject:theNews];
```

Comment: Are you sure that dataset is a NSMutableArray? If it isn't responding to removeObjectAtIndex: it might just be a NSArray.

Comment: It isn't a `NSMutableArray` if it doesn't respond to that selector. You might not create it correctly or mistakenly use a [`copy` property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220120/nsmutablearray-addobject-nsarrayi-addobject-unrecognized-selector-sent-to/3220137#3220137). If you have doubts try testing for it using `-isKindOfClass:`.

Comment: umble, it is not a NSMutableArray, but: @interface ListOfVideo : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> { NSMutableArray *dataSet; } @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *dataSet; ... // In the .m file @synthesize dataSet;

Comment: But how do you initialize it `dataSet`?

Comment: // viewDidLoad
dataSet = (NSMutableArray *) [[NewsFetcher sharedInstance] fetchManagedObjectsForEntity:@"News" withPredicate:predicate withDescriptor:@"Titolo"];
 [dataSet retain];

// updateDatabase ... this is when checking for new news from the net, I add them in the MutableArray.
[dataSet addObject:theNews];

Comment: Please update your question next time, code in comments is hard to read.

Comment: I'm sorry man, I'm new here :) Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your `NewsFetcher` returns you an immutable array, not a mutable instance. Use the following instead for initialization:

```
NSArray *results = [[NewsFetcher sharedInstance] 
                     fetchManagedObjectsForEntity:@"News" 
                     withPredicate:predicate
                     withDescriptor:@"Titolo"];
dataSet = [results mutableCopy];
```

An expression like `A *a = (A*)b;` only casts the pointer to a different type - it doesn't convert/change the actual type of the instance it points to.

Answer (score 5):

Verify that dataSet is an NSMutableArray.  The exception is getting thrown because it doesn't respond to removeObjectAtIndex.

Comment: Mumble, it is not a NSMutableArray, but:

@interface ListOfVideo : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {
 NSMutableArray *dataSet;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *dataSet;
...
// In the .m file
@synthesize dataSet;

Comment: The property being for a mutable array doesn't make the array magically become mutable.

Comment: @Joshua, while it doesn't "magically" make it mutable, it will prevent a mutable array from being mutated it it isn't properly defined.

Answer (score 1):

jdot is correct dataSet must be NSMutableArray..

you must do it this way..

```
  dataSet = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NewsFetcher sharedInstance] 
                               fetchManagedObjectsForEntity:@"News" 
                               withPredicate:predicate
                               withDescriptor:@"Titolo"]];
```

Now the dataSet is a mutable instance of the array you got from NewsFetcher and it won't crash on removing objects.