# Crash when removing an object from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableArray` that I've initialised in `viewDidLoad`:

```
 self.titlesTagArreys = [@[@"Dollar", @"Euro", @"Pound",@"Dollar longString", @"Euro longStringlongString", @"Pound",@"Dollar", @"Euro", @"PoundlongStringlongString"]mutableCopy];
```

in .h:

```
 @property(nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray* titlesTagArreys;
```

When I try to delete one item, the app crashes:

```
-(void)removeButtonWasPressed:(NSString*)tagTitle{
    NSLog(@"tagTitle - %@",tagTitle);
    NSLog(@"self.titlesTagArreys - %@",self.titlesTagArreys);    
    [self.titlesTagArreys removeObject:tagTitle];
}
```

Here is the log:

```
2013-08-06 16:15:03.989 EpicTv[6378:907] tagTitle - Dollar
2013-08-06 16:15:03.991 EpicTv[6378:907] self.titlesTagArreys - (
    Dollar,
    Euro,
    Pound,
    "Dollar longString",
    "Euro longStringlongString",
    Pound,
    Dollar,
    Euro,
    PoundlongStringlongString
)
[__NSArrayI removeObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c53bbd0
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI removeObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c53bbd0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x327162a3 0x3a5c197f 0x32719e07 0x32718531 0x3266ff68 0x20ad55 0x20c9a5 0x20bf5d 0x346090c5 0x34609077 0x34609055 0x3460890b 0x34608e01 0x345315f1 0x3451e801 0x3451e11b 0x362295a3 0x362291d3 0x326eb173 0x326eb117 0x326e9f99 0x3265cebd 0x3265cd49 0x362282eb 0x34572301 0xafb89 0xa4d68)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: Can you show the code that initializes your `NSMutableArray` because `removeObject` is a valid function for `NSMutableArray` but the error `unrecognized selector...` says that `titlesTagArreys` is not an `NSMutableArray`. Please share the code to do with `titlesTagArreys`.

Comment: @Luda how to declare NSMutableArray (titlesTagArreys) ?

Comment: @property(nonatomic, copy) makes a not mutable copy of you NSMutableArray. try @property(nonatomic, retain) instead of copy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that `titlesTagArray`s list not an `NSMutableArray` because `removeObject` can not be called. 
Maybe you passed an `NSArray` earlier in the code to `titlesTagArreys`.

try to `init` your Array with

```
self.titlesTagArreys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"...",@"...",...]];
```

@property(nonatomic, copy) makes a not mutable copy of you NSMutableArray. try @property(nonatomic, retain) instead of copy

Answer (score 5):

I also think that you `titlesTagArreys` is not mutable array because of some code changes

Try to add: `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass(self.titlesTagArreys.class));` to check what class do you use

```
-(void)removeButtonWasPressed:(NSString*)tagTitle{

  NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass(self.titlesTagArreys.class));

  [self.titlesTagArreys removeObject:tagTitle];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and learned that you must override the **setter** for the mutable array property and call `mutableCopy`. You'll find the answer in Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220120/nsmutablearray-addobject-nsarrayi-addobject-unrecognized-selector-sent-t/3220640#3220640).

Comment: This is only true if the property is defined with `copy`. If it is defined with `strong` (and not `copy`) then there is no need to override the setter method.

Answer (score 0):

titlesTagArray is not NSMutableArray. This is because , in the logs we can see [__NSArrayI removeObject:] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c53bbd0. 
Also NSArrayI is used for NSArray and NSArrayM is used for NSMutableArray. 
You must have initialised the mutablearray with an NSArray hence the exception.