# How to modify NSMutableSet using Fast Enumerations with NSPredicate as filter

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate, nsset

Newbie Questions,

I have **3 Class** , 3 of them are subclass of NSObject

**a. Collection Class**

This class will have 2 property

1. masterSongs (Contains all songs) declared as NSMUtableSet (copy, nonatomic)
2. listofPlaylists (contains all playlists) declared as NSMutableArray (copy, nonatomic)

**b. Playlist Class**

This Class will have 2 property

1. playListName declared as NSString
2. songLists    declared as NSMutableArray (strong, nonatomic), only store reference to the song not copy of song.

**c. Songs Class**

This Class has 4 property declared as NSString :

1. title
2. artist
3. playingtime
4. album

**Questions :**

1. I want to create removeSong method for Collection class, so when I delete particular song from Collection (masterSongs), it will also delete song in all of playList stored in Collection.listofPlaylists. but I am stuck with syntaxes*.

**I am using lookup method to create a NSSet and then using that set  to remove song object from NSMutableSet masterSongs using - minusSet: method*

also, I [found that](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsset.html) it's dangerous to change modify NSMutableSet while enumerating on it.

here I tried so far :

```
- (NSSet *) lookUpTitle: (NSString *)aName {

NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == %@",aName];

NSSet *result = [self.masterSongs filteredSetUsingPredicate:filter];

if ([result count] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"not found");

    return nil;
}


else{
    return result;
}
```

}

```
- (void) removeSong: (NSString *)zSong{


    for (Song *aSong in masterSongs) {



        if ([self lookUpTitle:zSong] != nil) {

            NSMutableSet *container = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:self.masterSongs];
        }

    }

}



 - (void) addSong :(Song *)aSong{
    if (![masterSongs containsObject:aSong]) {

        [masterSongs addObject:aSong];

    } }

-(void) addPlaylist: (Playlist *)aPlayList{

    if ([listOfPlaylists containsObject:aPlayList]==YES) {

    }
    else
        [listOfPlaylists addObject:aPlayList];


}

-(void) removePlaylist: (Playlist *)aPlayList{
    if ([listOfPlaylists containsObject:aPlayList]) {

        [listOfPlaylists removeObjectIdenticalTo:aPlayList];
    }

    else{
        ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just to emphasize it, though you did mention it, you ***cannot*** mutate a collection (set, array, dictionary) while enumerating over it.  It can (should and maybe will) throw an exception if you do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-lookUpTitle:` does most of the work for you. It returns a set of songs which need to be removed. You use `-minusSet:` to remove them from a `NSMutableSet`. To remove the songs from the playlists, you need to loop through your playlists and remove the songs in the set.  You use `-removeObjectsInArray:` to remove them from a `NSMutableArray`.

```
- (void)removeSong:(NSString *)zSong
{
    NSSet *targets = [self lookUpTitle:zSong];

    if ([targets count] > 0) {
        [self.masterSongs minusSet:targets];

        for (Playlist *playlist in self.listOfPlaylists) {
            // -allObjects converts the set into an array.
            [playlist.songLists removeObjectsInArray:[targets allObjects]];
        }
    }
}
```

---

You asked a new question about properties.

```
@property (copy) NSMutableSet *masterSongs;
```

Is a bad idea. A `-setMasterSongs:` method is automatically generated which will look something like this:

```
- (void)setMasterSongs:(NSMutableSet *)masterSongs
{
    if (_masterSongs != masterSongs) {
        _masterSongs = [masterSongs copy];
    }
}
```

The problem is `-[NSMutableSet copy]` returns an `NSSet`; similarly, `-[NSMutableArray copy]` returns `NSArray`. This is why you ran into a problem. [`NSSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [`NSArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) are immutable, so they don't contain any methods which will change their contents.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, was offline yesterday. I have questions regarding with property declaration.

I declared: NSMutableSet and NSMutableArray as Copy, Nonatomic on Collection Class

and I also declared NSMutableArray as strong, nonatomic on Playlist Class,

this condition, when I run Collection instance 
method addSong:(Song *)aSong or method addPlaylist:(Playlist *)aList

both method throw unrecognized selector exception. but when I changed Collection Class property both NSMutableArray and NSMutableSet to strong, nonatomic, it run properly.

so, Copy can't contain references or what?

Comment: some information about my last question is in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220120/nsmutablearray-addobject-nsarrayi-addobject-unrecognized-selector-sent-t but I still don't get it, why copy throw exception in addSong method, although Collection Class masterSongs declared as copy, nonatomic and Song property also declared as copy

Comment: @user3213703 these are new questions. You really should post them as a new question instead of tacking them onto an unrelated question.

Comment: @user3213703 I updated my answer with a short answer to you new question.

Comment: thanks for both of your answer & advice, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: regarding to NSPredicate query like my code above, it didn't work properly when I tried to run it. from my previous exercise my NSPredicate worked, but while I am trying to apply it on this case, it didn't work out, strange. if you don't mind, could you please look at it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962546/how-to-use-nspredicate-to-filter-nsmutableset-which-contains-composite-object-fr